# Single word for 'greater purpose'

Tags: single-word-requests, loanwords

I have heard this word, but I just can't remember it. It is a **3 to 5 letter word**, probably **2 syllabled**, and begins with letter **T**.

I am not totally sure if it's an English word. The context I have heard it in "whether there is *a greater purpose of life*." Or something like "Does the universe have 'a greater purpose'."
It was in one of the videos of a YouTube channel called exurb1a (I am not telling you to look through all of his videos to find the word, although it is an interesting channel).

Sorry if the question is not exactly a single word request, because it's more like a *word identification request* but such tag doesn't exist :D.

Comment: I think the word you’re looking for is ***teleology***, though it’s more than 5 letters and more than 2 syllables and does not precisely mean “greater purpose”. But it does start with a `T` and is commonly invoked in philosophical explorations of an “ends-seeking” nature to the universe. It comes from the Greek `teleos` (lit. *ends*, metaphor. *purpose*) and `logos` (*word* / *study of*).

Comment: Close enough! I was looking for **telos** which is infact where the the word teleology originates from.

Comment: Yep, I mentioned that in my final sentence ;) But *telos* is not an English word (which you wanted was a risk in your Q), and here on EL&U we’re restricted to offering answers from the lexicon of English.

Comment: Well, I just looked it up and found it here: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/telos. Perhaps another word that English adopts as it is haha. Anyway, i think you should make it an answer, because *teleology/telos* is what I was looking for.

Comment: well it's not english, and not 5 letters ; but it has a t in it... raison d'être

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there are no answers to this question, and a comment has more or less already been accepted as the answer, I thought I'd record the answer for posterity with a little further explanation.

Dan Bron's suggestion [teleology](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/teleology):

> The explanation of phenomena in terms of the purpose they serve rather
>   than of the cause by which they arise. - OLD.

Refers to explaining phenomena in terms of *the purpose they serve*.

The word is grounded in two other words *teleos* and *telos* as explained on [Vocabulary.com:](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/teleology)

> We can trace the origin of teleology to the Greeks: to teleos, meaning
>   "complete," and its root telos, meaning "result." Then we add the
>   suffix -logy, which means "logic," or "reason." The philosophy itself
>   suggests that acts are done with a foregone purpose in mind — people
>   do things knowing the result they wish to achieve. As Aristotle said,
>   "Nature does nothing in vain." So far, there's no teleology to explain
>   why you haven't left the couch for several hours.

[Telos can also mean](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/telos) the ultimate object or aim:

> An ultimate object or aim.
>
> in the hedonistic life, people lose some moral purpose, a telos which
>   provides the moral justification for the society. - OLD.

And in this instance as asserted by the questioner, was the word that the question attempted to reveal.

Comment: good to record the proper answer!